# Find two closed subsets or real numbers such that $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\cap B=\varnothing$

Tags: general-topology

Here is my problem:

> Find two closed subsets or real numbers such that $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

I tried to use the definition of being close for subsets like intervals but I couldn't find any closed sets. Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: i think there's a few questions on the same topic, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250254/can-distance-between-two-closed-sets-be-zero

Comment: $\phi$ (`\phi`) is not the same symbol as $\emptyset$ (`\emptyset`) or $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing`).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Yes I checked the edit and know what is the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** You cannot do this for bounded closed sets. Think about $\Bbb N$ and a set $\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ such that $\lim\frac n{a_n}=1$.

Comment: Thank you Asaf. It was a nightmare

Comment: The condition that $\lim (n-a_n)=0$ seems more promising than $\lim\frac{n}{a_n}=1$.

Answer (score 16):

Take the following two sets:

$$A = \mathbb{N}$$
$$B = \{n + 2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Then both are obviously closed subsets of the reals, and for any $\varepsilon>0$ you have some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$, and thus $d(A,B) = 0$.

Also notice that if you took one of the two sets to be bounded (say $A$), then it would be compact. In that case if $d(A,B) = 0$ you would have two sequences of points $S_A=\{a_n\}\subseteq A$ and $S_B=\{b_n\}\subseteq B$ such that $d(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow 0$. Then $S_B$ must be bounded by some $M$. $C = B\cap [-M,M]\supseteq S_B$ is compact. By compactness we get two convergent subsequences of $S_A$ and $S_B$. Their limits are contained in $A$ and $B$ respectively (since the sets are closed) and must be the same point since $d(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow 0$. This is a contradiction, and thus neither one of the sets can be bounded.

Comment: One tiny detail: $2$ is in both your $A$ and $B$ ($2 = 1 + \frac11$). Try replacing $B$ with $C = \{n + 2^{-n} \in \mathbb R \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: @kahen Wouldn't 1 be in both your sets assuming 0 is included in the natural numbers?

Comment: @MatsT Only dirty rotten set theorists (hi, Asaf :D) think that $0$ should be in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @MatsT: I usually denote by $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Answer (score 5):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a visual example is $A= \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ and $B= \{(x,e^x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following two sets: $$A=\{2,3,4,5,...\},~~~B=\{2\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{3},4\frac{1}{4},...\}$$